# How to cascade windows in windows 8 like in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

Is there a way to cascade your windows like you can in windows 7, exactly how windows 7 does it?

Comment: Flip3D is gone in Windows 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is still available by right clicking on the taskbar. It appears to be exactly the same.

If you were talking about the nifty feature shown below (Flip3D) activated via <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it is lost as that shortcut switches apps in Windows 8.

[image: 1]